# Extract frequency and dB from mp3 file

Tags: python, audio

given an mp3 file, I'd like to be able to extract a list of lists with frequency and dB reading for each frame of an audio file.

[[f_1, db_1], [f_2, db_2], ..., [f_n, db_n]]

I've been able to find the following code, which displays frequency and dB in a graph, here: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/librosa/librosa/blob/master/examples/LibROSA%20demo.ipynb

I've tried to read through the source code and determine a way to take the values used as inputs for the graph to convert them to the data structure I need, but I don't understand enough about audio processing terminology to understand what the source code is doing.

I'd appreciate any help on this project.

Thank you.